# Nonhomogeneous Poisson distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution

Suppose claims arrive at a firm with nonhomogeneous Poisson distribution where:
$\lambda(t)=$

{$t, \  0\leq t\leq 5$

$5, \ 5\leq t\leq 7$

$12-t, \ 7\leq t \leq12$}

(Sorry I don't know how to write the function out properly on latex)

$t$ is the time in months and we assume each month has $30$ days.

I'm asked to calculate the expected number of claims in a year and I just want to check I've done this right because there's one part I'm not too sure about in my answer.

Here's what I've done:

$\wedge(t) = \int^t_0 s ds = 1/2t^2, 0\leq t\leq 5$

$\wedge(t)=5+1/2(5)^2 = 17.5, 5\leq t \leq 7$

$\wedge(t)=17.5 + \int^t_7(12-s)ds = 17.5+12t-84-((t^2-49)/2) , 7\leq t \leq 12$

$N=17.5+12(12)-84-((12^2 -49)/2) = 30$

What's confusing me is the $5\leq t \leq 7$ part. To obtain $17.5$ from my second $\wedge (t)$ I only added $5$ once, should I have added it twice (or more than twice)? Does this interval mean that there are $5$ claims from month $5$ to month $7$ or does it mean there are $5$ claims each month from month $5$ to month $7$? Should my total by $35$ instead of $30$? I'm puzzled here because if I leave my answer this way then if I were to work out $\wedge(6)$ I would get $17.5$ as my answer but if I also work out $\wedge(7)$ I again get $17.5$, should $\wedge (7)$ be $22.5$?

Please let me know if I've done this correctly or if I've made a mistake, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected number of claims in 12 months is simply the integral of the intensity (claims rate) over that time period; i.e.
$$\operatorname{E}[N(12)] = \Lambda(12) = \int_{t = 0}^{12} \lambda(t) \, dt$$ where $$\lambda(t) = \begin{cases} t, & 0 \le t \le 5 \\ 5, & 5 < t \le 7 \\ 12 - t, & 7 < t \le 12.\end{cases}$$

The integration of $\lambda$ is straightforward:

$$\int_{t = 0}^{12} \lambda(t) \, dt = \int_{t=0}^5 t \, dt + \int_{t=5}^7 5 \, dt + \int_{t=7}^{12} (12-t) \, dt.$$  You don't need to explicitly compute $\Lambda(t)$ and write it as a piecewise function, which is what you were apparently trying to do, because all you need is the cumulative intensity at a single point in time.

---

For the sake of completeness, if you need to compute the cumulative intensity $\Lambda(t)$, then there are the following cases:

**Case 1.**  $0 \le t \le 5$:

$$\Lambda(t) = \int_{s=0}^t s \, ds = \frac{t^2}{2}.$$

**Case 2.**  $5 < t \le 7$:

$$\Lambda(t) = \Lambda(5) + \int_{s=5}^t 5 \, ds = \frac{25}{2} + 5(t-5) = 5t - \frac{25}{2}.$$

**Case 3.**  $7 < t \le 12$:

$$\Lambda(t) = \Lambda(7) + \int_{s=7}^t (12 - s) \, ds = 5(7) - \frac{25}{2} + 12t - \frac{t^2}{2} - 12(7) + \frac{7^2}{2} = -37 + 12t - \frac{t^2}{2}.$$

**Case 4.**  $t > 12$:

$$\Lambda(t) = \Lambda(12) + 0 = -37 + 12(12) - \frac{12^2}{2} = 35.$$

This gives the complete function

$$\Lambda(t) = \begin{cases} 0, & t < 0 \\
\frac{t^2}{2}, & 0 \le t \le 5 \\
5t - \frac{25}{2}, & 5 < t \le 7 \\
-\frac{t^2}{2} + 12 t - 37, & 7 < t \le 12 \\
35, & t > 12.
\end{cases}$$

We can then compute probabilities and expected intensities for intervals from one point in time to another, e.g. the expected number of claims between times $t = 4$ and $t = 8$ is $\Lambda(8) - \Lambda(4) = 27 - 8 = 19$.

Comment: The reason why I'm using $\wedge (t)$ is because there's another part of the question where I need the probability of, for example, 4 claims in time $t=2$ until $t=6$ ($4$ months). So I need to have a formula I can plug a value of $t$ into to get a solution. I probably should have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: I think my second $\wedge (t)$ is wrong, should it be $5\int^t_5 1ds$? Or is the constant value of $5$ correct?

Comment: @CharlieP See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi again, I've practiced these questions a lot and have got the hang of them now thanks to your help but I've just come across one question that is puzzling me just a bit, it uses the same function but asks me to find the expected number of claims in July, August, September and October which i believe can be found using: $\Lambda (11)-\Lambda (7)$ and I'm just not quite sure what to do for $\Lambda (7)$ since it appears twice; we have $5\leq t \leq 7$ and $7\leq t \leq 12$. In your complete function you have $7<t \leq 12$, is there a reason why it becomes $7<t$ instead of staying as $7\leq t$?

Comment: Or should it be $\Lambda (11)- \Lambda (6)$?

Comment: @CharlieP First of all, notice that $$5(7) - \frac{25}{2} = -\frac{7^2}{2} + 12(7) - 37 = \frac{45}{2}.$$  It doesn't matter which piecewise interval you take because both $\lambda(t)$ and $\Lambda(t)$ are continuous functions.  Second, if you want the expected number of claims from the beginning of July to the end of October, those correspond to time points $t = 6$ to $t = 10$, because $t = 0$ is the beginning of January. Then $t = 1$ is the end of January or beginning of February, and $t = 12$ is the end of December.